# Stacking list items without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi I would like to place list items containing images on top of each other  (like a stack of cards) without using absolute positioning.

This is the way I did it using absolute positioning.

```
.cards {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;  
    top:75px;  
}
```

and `cards` are `li` with an `img` inside.

But this causes problems when I resize the window or view my page on a mobile device. So I was thinking of placing my stack of cards within a centered container to keep the list items from moving around when the size of the window changes.

Here's my container

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="swing-stack">
       <li class="cards" ng-repeat="card in cards"><img ng-src="{{card.image}}"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe adding CSS `clear: both` would work?

Comment: Could you include an image or example of the "stack of cards" effect you are looking for? Are you looking for a bird's-eye view of a stack, or from the side?

Comment: A bird's-eye view where the user would only see one image but there would be more underneath the top image.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use absolute positioning to make this happen.  To help with the problem absolute positioning is causing you use a relative positioned div outside of them.  Absolute positioned items inside of a relative position container are positioned starting at the top left of its parent, not the page.

```
#cardsContainer {
    position:relative;
    top: 75px;
}

.cards {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;  
    top:0px;
}
```